# Cannot resolve symbol 'DateTime' android studio

Tags: java

I'm getting this error "Cannot resolve 'Date()'" and I don't know why.

If someone could explain why I'm getting it, I would be grateful.

Thank you

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lblDateAndTime = (TextView)
                findViewById(R.id.lblDateAndTime);
        Button btnDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
        btnDate.setOnClickListener(new
                                           View.OnClickListener() {
                                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                                   new DatePickerDialog(dateandtime.this, d,
                                                           myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                                           myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),

                                                           myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                                               }
                                           });
        Button btnTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTime);
        btnTime.setOnClickListener(new
                                           View.OnClickListener() {
                                               public void onClick(View v) { new
                                                       TimePickerDialog(dateandtime.this, t,
                                                       myCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                                                       myCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show();
                                               }
                                           });
        updateLabel();
    }// onCreate
}
```

Comment: Please post code *as text* in the question rather than as a screenshot. You haven't shown where the variable `dateandtime` is declared, either. Finally, we don't know what type you *expect* `DateTime` to resolve to, or what imports you've got.

Comment: Date or DateTime? Your title does not agree with the body text.

Comment: Provide a *minimal* code example, and include your `import` statements as requested by Skeet.

Comment: Almost certainly resolved in many other Questions and Answers. Search for java.util.Date (tip: avoid this class), Joda-Time, java.time, ThreeTen-Backport, ThreeTenABP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
import java.util.Date;
public class DateDemo {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // Instantiate a Date object
      Date date = new Date();

      // display time and date using toString()
      System.out.println(date.toString());
   }
}
```

Make sure you import java.util.Date.

Comment: yes I have done but there is no influence, still error (Cannot resolve symbol 'DateTime' )